# Invite methods does not exist

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I need all the invitations in show. This I want to do under a company when that company is selected must invite come forth only now I get the error.

Method invite does not exist (Im very new in Vue.js)

Overview.vue code

```
<v-container fluid grid-list-md>
   v-layout v-if="query === 'invites'" align-space-between justify-center row fill-height wrap>
   <span v-for="invite in invites" :key="invite.id">{{ invite.email }}</span>
</v-layout>
```

InviteController index:

```
public function index( Manager $fractal, InviteTransformer $inviteTransformer ) {

        Auth::user()->authorizeRoles( 'user.view' );

        // Get all companies
        $companies = Auth::user()->companies()->get();
        $invites = $companies->invites()->get();

        // Restructure for output
        $collection = new Collection( $invites, $inviteTransformer );
        $data = $fractal->createData( $collection )->toArray();

        return $this->respond( $data );
}
```

ComapnyModel:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Manage;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model {

    // This table does not have timestamps
    public    $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [ 'name' ];


    public function users() {

        return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\Manage\User' )->orderBy('lastname')->orderBy('firstname')->orderBy('id');
    }

    public function userIds() {

        return $this->users()->pluck('id');
    }

    public function admins() {

        return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Models\Manage\User' )->orderBy('lastname')->orderBy('firstname')->orderBy('id');
    }

    public function adminIds() {

        return $this->admins()->pluck('id');
    }

    public function invites() {

        return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\Manage\Invite' )->orderBy('email')->orderBy('id');
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your `Company` model? You probably don't have an `invites()` function there.

Comment: Added you can see him on the main post

Comment: This error is fixed i needed to remove ->get();

Comment: If you've fixed this issue, post your answer so that everyone knows you've managed it to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Ficed by myself i needed to remove ->get();